# Boost.Build conditional variable

Tags: boost, boost-build, bjam

How can I set a variable in Jamfile, that's value would depend on used feature ?

That is, I am using feature library:

```
import feature : feature ;

feature myoption : A B C : symmetric propagated ;
```

Now I want to set a global variable depending on  value?

```
constant MY_VARIABLE : >>HERE VALUE DEPENDING ON <myoption> VALUE<< ;
```

How this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

In Boost.Build, the expression "<myoption> value" doesn't make much sense unless given a concrete target's context. Different concrete targets can be built with different values for <myoption> during the same build invocation. Those different concrete targets can even come from the same metatarget, yet still have different values for <myoption>. If you can provide an example of what you are trying to do, that includes targets and specifies how MY_CONSTANT is to be used for them, then perhaps I can come up with a solution.

Edit: Here is the relevant FAQ entry: [How do I get the current value of feature in Jamfile?](http://www.boost.org/doc/display_build.php/boost-build/boost-build/doc/html/bbv2/faq.html#bbv2.faq.featurevalue)